# Using OpenId login with Facebook

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, stack-overflow

I want to develop application where user can log in with Facebook OpenID( same functionality as provided by stackoverflow) in rails application. Please suggest me any tutorial or gem for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Omniauth? Just try and watch tutorials..

[From Github to get Omniauth source](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)

[Many Tutorials about Omniauth](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth)

[Facebook authentication with omni-auth tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast)

Good luck!